# Reduce the border/attach iframe border to another

Tags: css, r, shiny

Below is the sample iframe app in R shiny. Wanted to check if it is possible to reduce the border. I have attached below . Can anyone please help me

```
library(shiny)
members <- data.frame(name=c("Name 1", "Name 2"), nr=c('BCRA1','FITM2'))

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Getting Iframe"), 
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    fluidRow(
                      column(6, selectInput("Member", label=h5("Choose a option"),choices=c('BCRA1','FITM2'))
                      ))),
                  mainPanel(fluidRow(
                    htmlOutput("frame")
                  )
                  )
                ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({ 
    query <- members[which(members$nr==input$Member),2]
    test <<- paste0("http://news.scibite.com/scibites/news.html?q=GENE$",query)
  })
  output$frame <- renderUI({
    input$Member
    my_test <- tags$iframe(src=test, height=1000, width=1035, frameborder = "yes")
    print(my_test)
    my_test
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Reduce this (Like can we make "b" attached to "a"

[image]

Comment: HI all, Wanted to check if this is possible to achieve?:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and I think this is possibly the easiest answer (I may stand corrected here).

Your issue is/was down to your CSS for h2 (`margin-top:20px`). I have wrapped your `titlePanel` in a `div` and gave it an id (`test`) to only control the CSS for that particular element. Next I added some specific CSS directly to your code `tags$style("#test h2 {margin-top: 10px;}")`. This should control the `margin-top` specifically for your `titlePanel` and shouldn't affect any subsequent uses of `titelPanel` or `h2()`.

You can control the space by setting **margin-top: 10px;** to the amount of `px` you like.

```
library(shiny)
members <- data.frame(name=c("Name 1", "Name 2"), nr=c('BCRA1','FITM2'))

ui <- fluidPage(tags$style("#test h2 {margin-top: 10px;}"), # add style here
                div(id = "test", titlePanel("Getting Iframe")), # add id here
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    fluidRow(
                      column(6, selectInput("Member", label=h5("Choose a option"),choices=c('BCRA1','FITM2'))
                      ))),
                  mainPanel(fluidRow(
                    htmlOutput("frame")
                  )
                  )
                ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({ 
    query <- members[which(members$nr==input$Member),2]
    test <<- paste0("http://news.scibite.com/scibites/news.html?q=GENE$",query)
  })
  output$frame <- renderUI({
    input$Member
    my_test <- tags$iframe(src=test, height=1000, width=1035, frameborder = "yes")
    print(my_test)
    my_test
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```